# Fritz!Box 7490 (Fritz!OS 6.30): Which USB ext. HDD actually work in USB3 mode?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, usb-3, fritzbox

I have an external USB3.0 Transcend StoreJet (model TS1TSJ25M3) 1TB HDD connected to my Fritz!Box 7490 (tested both with official Fritz!OS 6.30 and "laboratory beta" 113.06.36-31504 BETA).

When connected to the Fritz!Box's USB3 port *and* using setting "Power Mode
USB 3.0", the Fritz!Box doesn’t detect the device. After switching to "Green Mode USB 2.0", the device is detected, indexed and I can read from and write to it. Unfortunately, only with USB2 speed …

AVM (the maker of Fritz!Box) simply state

> Some USB 3.0 storage devices (for example My Passport hard drives from Western Digital) do not correctly identify themselves as USB 3.0 devices, which means that FRITZ!Box cannot integrate them as such. Therefore, check whether the USB storage device is detected correctly when you connect it to your computer.

Since I currently do not own any PC that has USB3 ports, I went to a friend and we tried the drive on both his Linux Mint 17.2 and Windows 8.1 systems—no problem whatsoever and USB3 speeds.

Since I quite like the Transcend "Anti-Shock" external drives, I was planning to buy a new (bigger) one (like 2 or 3TB) but of course after this experience I wonder what drives actually "correctly identify themselves as USB 3.0 devices" so that they could be used with my Fritz!Box 7490 (and on my next Linux PC, hopefully with USB3).

So my questions are:

- Does anyone of you actually *use* an external 2TB/3TB drive that you *definitely know* works in USB3 SuperSpeed mode on a Fritz!Box 7490? Recommendations welcome!
- Does anybody know the technical reasons behind it or maybe a way to make it work?
- Is there any safe way to somehow detect if a drive will be working as a "correctly identified USB3 device" if I only have (Linux) PCs with USB2 ports?

Thanks in advance for any tried-and-true recommendations and/or technical insights!

---

Some more info to avoid off-topic questions:

- Upon first testing, the drive had been MBR-partioned (1 partition), using Window’s *NTFS* file system.
- After I finished testing at my friend’s place, I re-partitioned it using MBR and the *ext4* (Linux) file system, using still only 1 partition. (So no *GPT*.)
- Yes, the Fritz!Box 7490's Fritz!OS 6.30 actually *does* now support *ext4*, and I'm very happy about it, because AVM’s docs still only talk about *FAT*, *NTFS*, and *ext2*. (Though *ext3* was already supported for some time now.)
- No, the symptoms do *not* change when I reformat and use the drive with another file system (like NTFS or ext2).

Hope this helps. ;-)